# Mongodb 'layout' for a huge number of combinations

Tags: mongodb, matrix

I have a MySQL table (Table1) with 2000 rows, each row storing data of a 3d object: size, location, name, etc.
The second table (Table2) contains a list of properties for the 3d objects listed in Table1; every object can have multiple entries in this table or none. In this particular case let's say we have 10.000 entries.
Here's the difficult part: there is a combination between each and every Table2 entry which gives a distance. So here's the 3rd table (Table3) which looks like:

```
row1:         table2_entry1 table2_entry2 result  
row2:         table2_entry1 table2_entry3 result  
....  
rowN:         table2_entry1 table2_entryN result  

rowN+1:       table2_entry2 table2_entry1 result  
rowN+2:       table2_entry2 table2_entry3 result  
....  
rowN+N:       table2_entry2 table2_entryN result  
....  
....  
rowN+N+...+N: table2_entryN table2_entryN-1 result
```

Therefore Table3 will have 10.000.000 entries. I know, using a matrix will cut it in half as there are pairs of (entry1, entry2, same_result) and (entry2, entry1, same_result).

A mongoDB document will look like this (e.g. for entry1)

```
{  
 "_id": ObjectID("..."),  
 "location": "some_file_location",  
 ...  
 "media_properties": {  
      {entry2: result,    
       entry3: result,  
       ...  
       entryN: result,  
 }  
}
```

thus "media_properties" will have 9.999 dictionary pairs for each of the 10.000 properties stored in Table2.
I'm not convinced this is the best approach of storing my huge number of combinations.

Should I use a separate collection to store all the combinations like in the SQL table or should I embed the dictionary in the media document (like the above example)?

I would like to get rid of the overhead and not store the same information twice. In this case I could have something like:

```
entry1 - entry2 - result  
entry2 - entry3 - result
```

etc.

instead of:

```
entry1 - entry2 - result  
entry2 - entry1 - result
entry2 - entry3 - result
entry3 - entry2 - result
```

etc

Is it possible to "map" half a matrix into a mongoDB document?
Are there any better solutions to store this?

Any idea is welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kinds of queries do you need to run?  All of entry1's results?  Finding the entry1-entry2 result?  Finding the entry #s for a certain result?

Comment: I will need to sort the results (asc/desc) given any entry. Actually the result it's a hough distance between the two 3d objects (entry1 - entry2) and what I need is to get the best matches of a given 3d object (similarity search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd discourage keeping many of them in one document, as you won't be able to sort them nor take out partial information of such huge jsons (if not structured by fields). Also there's maximal document size without using GridFS (16MB). 
Keeping one "entry-entry + result" per document seems like a waste of space (a bit), but it should really work well for your needs and get you the proper performance of querying - even if you'd need to query over elements and not results - additional index should nail it. Also write performance (adding many new results to new elements as new documents over adding result to the end of documents) should not be discouraging. I'd like to hear how it went :)